# Find Deleted File in an AppFolder

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

How do I find a file that was deleted and had a relative path of `/foo/baz.txt`?

I am using the `/v1.0` endpoint and my app requests the `Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder` scope. I can access `/drive/special/appRoot`.

Will `/drive/special/appRoot:/search(q='baz.txt')` find deleted files? 
Will `/drive/special/appRoot:/foo/baz.txt:/versions`versions for a deleted file?

There is not a lot of examples (or documentation support) for using AppFolder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't possible today.

When a file is deleted from OneDrive (either via the Web App or the API), it is sent to the Recycle Bin and held for 30 days (assuming the user doesn't manually empty it of course).

At the moment, it isn't possible to access or restore a `DriveItem` from a dive's Recycle Bin ([this has been discussed](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-api-docs/issues/807#issuecomment-375378034) but I'm unaware of any ETA). The only way to [restore an item](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/restore-deleted-files-or-folders-in-onedrive-949ada80-0026-4db3-a953-c99083e6a84f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) today is for the user to do so via the [OneDrive Web App](https://onedrive.com).

Comment: I did find some posts from 2012 that indicated the functionality was missing,  I AssUMed it would have been addressed by now. Both options I identified above or a listing of the recycle bin itself would be a nice option to find a deleted item, as well as the ability to restore an idententified item. Why is there a deleted tag for an item if you can't every find one ?

Comment: I believe that property is only populated when calling the `/delta` endpoint. It tells you if a file has been deleted since the last time you pulled the delta. This is important if you're building a sync client since you need to know if you should remove a file from the local drive.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suppose you want to get a file that was deleted in App Folder.

Based on my test, we can use the following API to get the file in App Folder:

`/drive/special/approot:/foo/baz.txt:/`

However, if we deleted the file, it will return a 404 status code when we use this API.

We can get the file by using this API unless we restore it in the Recycle bin of OneDrive.

Comment: Looking for info on the rest API to find/restore this item.  Also hoping I do not need to expand the scope to Files.ReadWrite to do so.